# A question on nilpotent linear operator on finite dimensional vector space with dimension same as degree of nilpotency

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a nilpotent linear operator of index $n>1$ ($T^n$ is the null operator but $T^{n-1}$ is not ) on a vector space of dimension $n$ ; then how do we prove that there is no linear operator $S$ on $V$ such that $S^2=T$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By contradiction assume that there's $S$ such that $S^2=T$ then

$$0=T^{n}=S^{2n}$$
hence $S$ is nilpotent hence  $S^n=0$ but
$$0\ne T^{n-1}=S^{2n-2}\implies 2n-2\le n-1\iff n\le1\leftarrow\text{contradiction}$$

Comment: Note that this is based on the result that a nilpotent endomorphism $N$ of a space of dimension $n$ satisfies $N^n=0$. This is not hard to prove, but still harder than the rest of the argument here.